# Mapping an Interface to a Default Type in NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, interface, nhibernate-mapping

Is it possible to say:

```
var user = session.Get<IUser>(1);
```

Where IUser is an interface and has an implentation called User. The User class is mapped to the Users table and I would like to use this as the default type when doing a Get/Query in NHibernate.

I'd appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is no. NHibernate requires you to map and specify concrete classes.

There is a long and messy answer involving joined-subclass mappings that sort-of works, in that it allows you to map an interface type and then all the concrete types implementing that interface that can be persisted, but it doesn't really give you what you seem to want, which is the ability to map the interface properties to the DB and then get / save any old entity that satisfies the interface, with a specified default type.

You could write some kind of wrapper around `ISession` that would let you do what you want - ie, translated any call to `wrapper.Get<IUser>(id)` to `session.Get<User>(id)`, but then you'd be basically just tying `IUser` to being an alias for `User` which really goes against the whole reason for using the interface in the first place.

(Aside: if you were using interfaces simply for IoC purposes, ie there will be a one-to-one mapping between IUser and a concrete type in 'normal' operation, with, say, a mocked User for test purposes, then what you can do is wrap NHibernate behind a repository which knows how to talk to your IoC solution to get the concrete type, and then act accordingly. Queries still work as expected because of implicit conversions. I've done this and it works, but it's a bit messy.)

Comment: Thanks, it's kind of the answer i was expecting but still good to hear someone else say it. It looks like abit of refactoring is in order.